# RadGrid pager localization

Tags: localization, telerik, telerik-grid, radgrid, pager

In RadGrid i couldn't find the localization settings for the
`GO` and `Change` buttons 
when the `RadGrid pager` is set to `Advanced mode`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must modify the `App_GlobalResources` file used by the `RadGrid` control.

1. In the Solution Explorer, there should be a file named `RadGrid.Main.xx-XX.resx` under the `App_GlobalResources` folder, where `xx-XX` is your language (de-DE).

   1b. If the `RadGrid.Main.xx-XX.resx` file is not there, copy the file named `RadGrid.Main.resx` and rename the copy as in step 1.

   1c. If the `RadGrid.Main.resx` is not yet in your project, add it to the `App_GlobalResources` folder. The file should be within your `Telerik` installed files (ex.: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Telerik\RadControls for ASP.NET AJAX Q3 2012\App_GlobalResources`).
2. Open that file and modify the keys `GoToPageLinkButtonText` and `ChangePageSizeLinkButtonText`.
3. Don't forget to set the `Localization` property of your `RadGrid` to the correct culture (`xx-XX`).